# Constant rank map between matrix manifolds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, matrix-calculus

I want to know what conditions are required to be able to identify a function from a manifold of matrices to another manifold of matrices (e.g. GL(n,R) to GL(n,R)) as being full-rank, so that I can apply (for example) the constant rank theorem. I understand that this involves vectorizing both the domain and codomain, but this typically produces very messy expressions, and it's not clear how to prove that it is full-rank from this.

In particular, suppose I have an expression for the derivative of a matrix function in the form of a matrix of matrices (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Other_matrix_derivatives)), where the (i,j) entry is the derivative of the function with respect to the (i,j) element of the argument to the function. Intuitively it seems like I should be able to prove that the derivative is full-rank by proving that the rows of this matrix are linearly independent, where linear combinations of rows are done by multiplying each row by an arbitrary matrix rather than a scalar. Can anyone help me prove or disprove this, and is there a simpler way?

Comment: Don't try to compute the derivative as an unwieldy matrix. Instead, work with directional derivatives $df_A(B)$ and figure out dimensions of kernel/image from that.

Comment: Thanks, turns out that the problem I had was easily solved from this perspective.

Comment: Great :) I guess I should have made that an answer :)